# Is evil-mode compatible with the `python-mode.el`?

Tags: python, evil

Evil-mode has some minor wrinkles and unexpected effects when used with a few other major and minor modes, including org-mode.

Does Evil-mode, in Emacs 24.5, interfere with or reduce the functionality of python-mode.el?

Comment: // , If downvoting, please add a quick comment.

Comment: Try It And See™

Comment: // , Yeah, I am, but if I can find the answer, I want to save someone the trouble of popping open a VM just to see. This is one of those "somebody has probably tried this" things, but I might end up being the "somebody".

Comment: // , Whatever happens, I hope to offer a superior alternative product, as follows: Google it and Save Yourself a Half Hour and 2 GB of Disk Space™, @wasamasa

Comment: These kind of questions are pretty useless as with the complexity of Emacs it's become pretty much impossible to predict anything involving package interactions. In the first place Evil shouldn't result in any incompatibilities as it's mostly commands and keymaps you can tweak and deactivate as you wish, yet there are a few rare bugs interacting with other Emacs packages in unexpected ways. So, "Stop worrying, TIAS" is the only useful answer I can give you here.

Comment: // , Hm. "...pretty useless as with the complexity of Emacs it's become pretty much impossible to predict anything involving package interactions..." Maybe there should be a "long tail" flag for questions involving the possibility of unlikely problems. What sayest?

Comment: I think the best way to improve the question is to add more detail about types of problems you're concerned about, with indications of how they manifest in other modes.  In particular, it would be useful if you add links / details about the org mode incompatibilities you've described.  Otherwise, we don't even know what we're looking for.  As a concrete example: the one issue I've noticed with Evil has to do with polymode buffers, where crossing over an "embedded" indirect buffer toggles evil mode state.  So, if you're not using polymode, this particular issue will should not affect you.

Answer (score 4):

It should. In case of conflicts we are determined to solve them. Please report any issues here:

https://gitlab.com/python-mode-devs/python-mode/issues

Comment: This appears to be a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: Given the current question, I think this is a fine answer.